The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call Android
code
         hubConnection.start()
                 .subscribe({}, 
                { error ->
                  Log.e("HubConnection", "Error starting hub 
                 connection: $error")
                 hub connection.stop()
                            }

        hubConnection.onClosed {}

2-    and in subscription
  Completable.fromCallable {
                hubConnection.start().blockingAwait()
            }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({
                    if (hubConnection.connectionState == HubConnectionState.CONNECTED) {

                        val con = hubConnection.invoke(
                            "Subscribe",
                            hubConnection.connectionId,
                            arrayListOf(
                                currentUserId,
                                currentUserId + "methodName",
                                currentUserId + "methodName",
                                currentUserId + "methodName",
                                currentUserId + "methodName",
                                currentUserId + "methodName",
                                currentUserId + "methodName"
                            )
                        )

                        con.subscribe()

                        con.doOnError { error ->
                            hubConnection.stop()
                        }
                        con.retry(30000)


                    } else {
                        Log.e("connection: ", "not Established connection ......")
                    }
                }, { error ->
                    Log.e("HubConnection", "Error starting hub connection: $error")
                    hubConnection.stop()
                })

FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-19-thread-1
Process: com.gagamuller.plan.app, PID: 21170
io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing  method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | com.microsoft.signalr.HubException: An unexpected error occurred invoking 'Subscribe' on the server. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.observers.EmptyCompletableObserver.onError(EmptyCompletableObserver.java:50)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.CompletableSubject.onError(CompletableSubject.java:126)
at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection.lambda$invoke$19(HubConnection.java:669)
at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17.accept(Unknown Source:4)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.ReplaySubject$UnboundedReplayBuffer.replay(ReplaySubject.java:782)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.ReplaySubject.onError(ReplaySubject.java:385)
at com.microsoft.signalr.InvocationRequest.complete(InvocationRequest.java:29)
at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection.ReceiveLoop(HubConnection.java:492)
at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection.lambda$new$0$com-microsoft-signalr-HubConnection(HubConnection.java:162)
at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection$$ExternalSyntheticLambda32.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
at com.microsoft.signalr.LongPollingTransport.onReceive(LongPollingTransport.java:162)
at com.microsoft.signalr.LongPollingTransport.lambda$poll$8$com-microsoft-signalr-LongPollingTransport(LongPollingTransport.java:117)
at com.microsoft.signalr.LongPollingTransport$$ExternalSyntheticLambda13.run(Unknown Source:4)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: com.microsoft.signalr.HubException: An unexpected error occurred invoking 'Subscribe' on the server. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at com.microsoft.signalr.InvocationRequest.complete(InvocationRequest.java:29) 
at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection.ReceiveLoop(HubConnection.java:492) 
at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection.lambda$new$0$com-microsoft-signalr-HubConnection(HubConnection.java:162) 
at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection$$ExternalSyntheticLambda32.invoke(Unknown Source:2) 
at com.microsoft.signalr.LongPollingTransport.onReceive(LongPollingTransport.java:162) 
at com.microsoft.signalr.LongPollingTransport.lambda$poll$8$com-microsoft-signalr-LongPollingTransport(LongPollingTransport.java:117) 
at com.microsoft.signalr.LongPollingTransport$$ExternalSyntheticLambda13.run(Unknown Source:4) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
